# AWS API Gateway Returns entire Lambda response object as the body

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created an API in AWS API Gateway that integrates with a python Lambda function. Everything is working, except the API returns the ENTIRE python response object as the body of the response. Here is a static version of the response that the Lambda function returns to AWS API GW:

```
response = {
  "statusCode" : 400,
  "headers" : {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  },
  "body": <<variable containing some JSON>>
}
```

My understanding is that this is the correct format for the response--AWS API GW is supposed to parse this accordingly.

But when I run my API call, AWS API GW returns the entire response object as the body, and ignores the statusCode.

Here is a screen shot that shows this behavior.

[image]

I have tried various configurations on the API itself using mappings, but can't get this work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have an API Gateway integration to lambda?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, did you find what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing after all this time you have discovered the answer, but for anyone else that hits this and is trying to figure it out, it's in the API Gateway method definition - you have to ensure that `Lambda proxy integration` is set to true:

Go to your API Gateway, navigate to the method that is being handled by the lambda. Click the `Integration request` tab to check the setting, and edit if necessary.

[Screenshot showing where to find the Lambda proxy integration setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5fVX.png)